# How to restrict user to entering only "Y" or "N" in a single column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I want to restrict user entry in column A and column D.

In column A, the user should enter the values as `R00yyyyyy` where yyyyyy is a number between 000000 and 999999.

In column D they should only enter `y` or `n`.

My code below doesn't seem to work properly. The column A part works fine, just having issues with column D.

Can anyone suggest a way to enable restricting the entry in column D?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim rngCell As Range

If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rngCell In Target.Cells
    rngCell = UCase(rngCell)
    If rngCell.Characters.Count > 9 Then
    MsgBox ("Student number too long")
    rngCell.Clear
    End If
   If Not IsEmpty(rngCell.Value) Then
    Dim s As String
    Dim s1 As String
    Dim y As String
    Dim y1 As String
    s = CStr(rngCell.Value)
    s1 = Left(s, 3)
    y = CStr(rngCell.Value)
    y1 = Right(y, 6)
    If s1 <> "R00" Or Not IsNumeric(y1) Then
    MsgBox ("Must be in the form R00yyyyyy, where yyyyyy is a number between 000000 and 999999")
    rngCell.Clear
    End If
   Else
   End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim rngCell2 As Range

If Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each rngCell2 In Target.Cells
    rngCell2 = UCase(rngCell2)
    Dim b As String
    b = CStr(rngCell2.Value)
    If b <> "y" Or b <> "n" Then
    MsgBox ("The only allowable entry here is Y or N")
    End If
Next
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code below. It checks to see if the change was in either column A *or* column D and exits if neither column was changed.

Then you know that the change was in either column A or column D and check exactly which column. Then you do the appropriate check and show the appropriate message box depending on the input.

To check for a simple pattern like `R00yyyyyy` where `y` is a number you can use the [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator and use `#` as a placeholder for 'any number'.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngCell As Range

    ' exit if change was not in column A and not in column D
    If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A,D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' get first cell of change
    Set rngCell = Target.Cells(1, 1)

    ' disable events
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' now check if change in column A
    If rngCell.Column = 1 Then
        If Not rngCell.Value Like "R00######" Then
            MsgBox "Must be in the form R00yyyyyy, where yyyyyy is a number between 000000 and 999999"
            rngCell.Clear
        End If
    Else 'must have been in column D
        If rngCell.Value <> "y" And rngCell.Value <> "n" Then
            MsgBox "The only allowable entry here is Y or N"
            rngCell.Clear
        End If
    End If

    ' re-enable events
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the rest of your code is correct, you need to change your logical test from Or to And

```
If b <> "y" And b <> "n" Then
    MsgBox ("The only allowable entry here is Y or N")
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this line

```
 If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

So when they change anything in column D, it's not in A and the code exits before ever reaching your code for D

Comment: Is that what's happening? How do I fix that? I've been looking up all over websites for hours

Comment: You can check for change in column A _or_ column D with `If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A,D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Basically, I want the user to enter the values into column A as "R00yyyyyy" yyyyyy being a number between 000000 and 999999.

When they enter into column D, they are restricted to only using "y" or "n"